# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] : Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: api

```
app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    // Destructure Req Body
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    // Validate Body
    if (!email || !password) {
        res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: "PARAMS_MISSING" });
        
    }

    // Build the SQL query
    const query = `SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = "${email}"`;

    // Get the user from DB
    const user = await db(query);

    // Check if password is valid
    const isPasswordValid =  decryptPassword(user.hash_password, password);

    // Return if password is not valid
    if (!isPasswordValid) {
        res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: "INAVLID_PASSWORD" });

    }
       
    
    // Generate Token
    const token = generateToken({ id: user.id, email: user.email });

    // Save Cookie
    res.cookie("token", token, { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });
     res.end();
    // Return
    res.json({ success: true, message: "USER_AUTHENTICATED" });
});
```

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

I m getting this error again n again idk what to do i m beginner,
I'm facing this weird issue in NodeJS when using with Passport.js, Express. Basically, I get an error saying "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" even though I don't send more than one header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means the 'res' object respond twice. E.g: in your '`// Validate body`' if the password or email are missing your http connection respond '`res.status().json()`.'(note that is closing the http connection), but as you didn't stop the execution of the code, it carries on then it may respond a second time in the `// Return if password is not valid` which create the err as the header can not be set twice and the connection is already close.

Than more here you error is Unhandled, as an Async function reject, the error must be handle, wrapping the code in a try{} catch(e){} will fix it.

So that should fix your issues

```
app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    try{
    // Destructure Req Body
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    // Validate Body
    if (!email || !password) {
        res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: "PARAMS_MISSING" });
        return // stop execution of the function
        
    }

    // Build the SQL query
    const query = `SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = "${email}"`;

    // Get the user from DB
    const user = await db(query);

    // Check if password is valid
    const isPasswordValid =  decryptPassword(user.hash_password, password);

    // Return if password is not valid
    if (!isPasswordValid) {
        res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: "INAVLID_PASSWORD" });
        return // stop exec of the function

    }
       
    
    // Generate Token
    const token = generateToken({ id: user.id, email: user.email });

    // Save Cookie
    res.cookie("token", token, { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });
     res.end();
    // Return
    res.json({ success: true, message: "USER_AUTHENTICATED" });
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err) // code to handle the err
    }
});
```

But still, a problem remain as at the end of your script, you have a res.end()(which terminate the connection) and right after a res.json() which will fail as the connection has been close  the line before (than more the statusCode is missing)

Comment: I tried this method but it's not working I m still not able to log_in but although the error is gone I m not getting the error in return so thank u for that !!  I m using postman for HTTP request n its show the invalid password as I mentioned in my code!

Comment: if u get the err message for invalid password, it s good. Did you correct the end of your code (remove the res.end() and complete the res.status(200).json({ success:true....))

Comment: Yes, I did but the problem remains the same invalid_password!!

Comment: are you sure your password is valid ? and make sure the logic to validate it works ? bc you see the res come from here "// Return if password is not valid"

Comment: Yes, I checked it too!!

Comment: which package do you use to encrypt and decrypt your password ? if you get this message in your response it means this condition pass (if (!isPasswordValid) {), so i believe your pb is from here.

Comment: I m using bcrypt for encryption n decryption of passwords

Comment: did you build the dependencies ?? see this page https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/wiki/Installation-Instructions. For a simple auth systhem bcryptjs is better(simpler at least, and enought) https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs